# How to close parent UI window when child UI window is open in QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have multiple UI windows in my QT project. When a new UI window opens, the previous UI window must be closed, that is, at every point of time only one UI window must be open. How can this be done?

Comment: Have a look at QStackedWidget as it may fit your use case and elaborate on your question if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did that before and i suggest you to not close(delete) UI.

just hide it and when you need it show it again.

check this code:

when user click to see second UI:

```
void MainApp::on_btnSettings_clicked()
{
    this->hide();
    settingsManager = new SettingsManager(); // put this line in constructor
    settingsManager->show();
}
```

on second UI on closing form(or back button) emit a signal:

```
void SettingsManager::closeEvent(QCloseEvent *event)
{
    emit settingsBackToMainApp();
}
```

on main hide second class and show main:

```
void MainApp::settingsBackToMainApp()
{
    settingsManager->hide();
    this->show();
}
```

connect signal to slot:

```
connect(settingsManager,&SettingsManager::settingsBackToMainApp,this,&MainApp::settingsBackToMainApp); // put this line in constructor
```

Comment: could yo be more specified? I dont know where to put connect and also when I put settingsBackToMainApp() in second ui, I get `user of indeclared identifier`