# Qt multi-window and multi-thread architecture

Tags: multithreading, qt, qt5, multi-window

I am new to Qt5 and I am working on an embedded project, following is the technical background:

Embedded OS: Linux

Qt version: 5.3

LCD: 7 inch

Finally two programs run on the system, one is the main control unit (with xenomai) using C language, the other is Qt for the LCD GUI. In the Qt program, I need two extra threads, one for the socket communication between the Qt and the main control unit, the other thread is used for the serial port (I have a customized keyboard using RS232).

It will have around 10 windows, so I need to switch them one by one, only one is shown on the LCD at a time. The Qstackedwidget is good for this? And how to manage the communication between the windows and the main Qt application? I am a little confused about the whole architecture.

Should I created these 10 windows at the very beginning?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: In Qt all UIs are in Main Thread, you have to make Serial & TCP classes (with threads) and use signals to communicate with UIs (`Main Thread`).

Comment: For switching windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45802206/5068056

Comment: For switching multi windows, first: I have much more than 2 windows,  second: in each window, it still need to communicate with the serial and the socket, it looks the system need another class to manage these actions.

Comment: NO, you can make a TCP class and `move to thread` it, then your class will become a second thread, although TCP class UI is in main thread.

Comment: Try your best to keep logic like serial and socket communication separate from your GUI. You can use a `std::unique_ptr<QWidget> current_widget;` in your `MainWindow` and then do `current_widget = std::make_unique<SerialWindow>(this);` which should get rid of the previous window and show the new window.

Comment: For switching it's easy, just use signals to change and the above link is explain it very well. ---- imagine each time you receive data you want to show data length in UI, you should emit a signal and update the UI. not directly accessing UI.

Comment: @nwp: thanks for your reply. This solution is similar with the one my colleague have done, he makes 10 windows inherit from a base_window class, which has some pure virtual functions, all the logic is through a current_window object. But I this may be not the Qt de facto way...So I come here to ask.