# passing a text from one form to another in C++

Tags: c++, qt

I have two forms, one with QLineEdit and a button. other form have only QLabel. when somebody enters a text into first form and click the button, I need to open the second form displaying the text in the QLabel of second form. please any example how to do this will be highly appreciated.

and I'm doing this project in QT creator

Comment: Read this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

Comment: This is a simple signal slot example that i answered before but it could help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45802206/5068056

Comment: Also you can use static variables, assign your text and use it in second form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many options to achieve this. I'll show you one.
When you press the button, the form should appear.
Let's give it a text in a constructor which should be written on a label

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked() {
    if (ui->lineEdit->text().isEmpty()) {
        //
    }

    Form *form = new Form(ui->lineEdit->text());
    form->show();
}
```

In your QWidget or QDialog form

```
#include "form.h"
#include "ui_form.h"

Form::Form(QString value, QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Form)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->label->setText(value);
}

Form::~Form()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: hello sir then it says no matching function to call form::form(Qstring). please help me..

Comment: do you have Form.h 

public:
    explicit Form(QString value, QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Form(); ?

Comment: yes sir i fixed it. thnk you sooo much.. i will mark you answer as usefull.

Comment: sir please one more thing, can we do the same thing with signals and slots.? if it is possible how we can do it?

Comment: The signal and the slots in my mind are nothing to do here.

Comment: @Taz742  Indeed it's a typical possible usage of Qt signal/slot mecanism. Your solution is an initialisation one :  the text of the second form won't be updated if the QLineEdit text change.
Signal/Slot allow to connect the click of the first form button  to setting the text in the second form

Comment: @sandwood Yes, i know about you are talking it, but in this case, AlexDRex question is different.